# Error saving photo in Emulator - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator

Every time I take a photo with the Emulator and I click to save, the camera app stops working, it returns to normal activity and gives this error in logcat, it is not my app that stops working, it is the camera at the moment I click save photo.

API level 16

> 04-18 20:35:39.961 1913-2390/insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.xiope E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
>
> 04-18 20:35:42.701 1913-2390/insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.xiope E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service
>
> 04-18 20:35:42.711 1913-2390/insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.xiope E/FA: Discarding data. Failed to send event to service
>
> 04-18 20:35:45.311 1913-1913/insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.xiope E/EGL_emulation: tid 1913: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
>
> 04-18 20:35:45.341 1913-2390/insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.xiope E/FA: Failed to send current screen to service

Does anyone know how to solve or what can be?
On a real handset it works perfectly.

save picture:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_PHOTO) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        
            String imagePath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
    
            ocorrencia.arImagens.add(0, imagePath.split(" "));

            PicturesAdapter adapter = (PicturesAdapter) mRecyclerView.getAdapter();
            pictures p = new pictures(imagePath);
            adapter.addListItem(p, mList.size());
            
        } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while taking a photo. Error " + resultCode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have assign a value for SD card memory?

Comment: what's emulator sdk level?

Comment: Api level is 16

Comment: @Quimbo No, the way to save as images is local, but even then, would that be necessary?

Comment: @WotonSampaio In some cases it is necessary. Can you show the code you use to save the image? It may be that you are using an incorrect directory. You can use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` to save the file.

Comment: @Quimbo I added the code, the problem is that it works on a real device, so I think it's the emulator